# Paths in an Angular library

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have seen a few places that say you can use tsconfig paths in your library.
I have tried to set it up, but my project will not compile.
The full path to my services is **example-project/projects/example-project/src/lib/_core/services** so I have added this to my **tsconfig.ts** file (in the foot folder):

```
"paths": {
  "@core": ["src/app/_core"],
  "@configs": ["src/app/_core/configs"],
  "@models": ["src/app/_core/models"],
  "@services": ["src/app/_core/services"],
  "@validators": ["src/app/_core/validators"]
}
```

But if I try to reference a service from my library, it will not compile:

[image]

Here is the full class:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CloudinaryModule } from '@cloudinary/angular-5.x';
import * as Cloudinary from 'cloudinary-core';

import { IMAGES_CONFIG, ImagesConfig } from '@configs';
import { ResponsiveImageComponent } from './responsive-image.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ResponsiveImageComponent],
  exports: [ResponsiveImageComponent, CloudinaryModule],
  imports: [CommonModule, CloudinaryModule],
})
export class ImagesModule {
  static forRoot(config: ImagesConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: ImagesModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: IMAGES_CONFIG, useValue: config },
        ...CloudinaryModule.forRoot(Cloudinary, {
          cloud_name: config.cloudName,
        }).providers,
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How many modules in solution? What are their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. Two things.

I forgot to add the index.ts file in the directory, for example:

```
export * from './core-config.token';
export * from './core-config';
export * from './images-config.token';
export * from './images-config';
```

And the second thing I got by looking at a normal application with paths. The **baseUrl** in **tsconfig** is set to "./" so the path must be from there, so I changed my **tsconfig** to this:

```
"paths": {
  "@core": ["projects/example-project/src/app/_core"],
  "@configs": ["projects/example-project/src/app/_core/configs"],
  "@models": ["projects/example-project/src/app/_core/models"],
  "@services": ["projects/example-project/src/app/_core/services"],
  "@validators": [
    "projects/example-project/src/app/_core/validators"
  ]
}
```

and it works now.